# Problems creating sidebar toggle dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on http://www.variied.com/market/men/. I'm trying to create a toggle dropdown menu on the sidebar that is triggered when someone hits the "Tops" link on the sidebar, which will then toggle the content in the sub-menu to be displayed. Here's my current code

```
<style>
ul.category ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu li a{
display:none
}
</style>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery("#menu-item-746").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next("ul.category ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu li a").toggle();
        return false;   
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: The toggle is not working. Also check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/jscw045q/

Comment: why not just use a custom style accordion? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score -1):

There are a few issues in this fiddle:

1. You have a class called `#submenu` it should just be `submenu`
2. You're passing the `event` so you can use `e.preventDefault()` (unless you prefer `return false`)
3. I would suggest setting the subnav `ul` to `display: none` and just toggling that and I would use `slideToggle` for a nicer effect.

**JS**

```
$("#menu-item-746").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="submenu">
   <li  id="menu-item-746"><a href="#">Test Item</a></li>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.submenu ul{
  display: none;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jscw045q/4/)

**UPDATE**

I looked at your HTML on your site and it appears that your `ul` subnav is a child of your `li` not a sibling (it was a sibling in your fiddle). Try this:

```
$(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
```

Also from the code you have provided you are targeting an `id` which means this would only work for that 1 element. It appears the ones with a subnav have a class called `.menu-item-has-children` so I would target that, like so:

```
$(".sub-menu .menu-item-has-children").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).find("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

**NEW UPDATE**

Target the `a` instead then:

```
$(".sub-menu .menu-item-has-children").on("click", " a:first", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: That works for the Tops link, but now the other links do not toggle

Comment: What do you mean the other links do not toggle?

Comment: Try clicking on Bottoms, Outerwear, Accessories, etc.

Comment: they're toggling for me

Comment: They toggle in Chrome, but not FireFox

Comment: it's working in my firefox as well. To be clear, you're saying when you click, for example, "outerwear" the submenu does not slide down? Correct?

Comment: @AlexBlock do you know what version you're using? its working fine for me and to be honest this is simple JS that really should work no matter which browser. There's nothing unconventional about it

Comment: I'm using FireFox 34.0.5. In chrome, they all expand properly, but I when I click the links, I don't get redirected.

Comment: ohhh ok you have to add `a:first` in your click function, I updated my answer awhile ago but you probably missed it. Check it out above

Comment: @AlexBlock I found another issue which prevents the other links from toggling, change the click event to `.on()` and delegate the first `a` of the one clicked: `$(".sub-menu .menu-item-has-children").on("click", " a:first", function(e) {` see answer above